# Django-nonrel on Google App Engine, getting error i'm using Django 0.96

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I'm using Django Appengine http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine so I can use Django 1.3 and everything seems to work fine.

However, when opening pages my PyDev console (OS 10.6, Aptana Studio 2.0, Python 2.5) puts out this message:

> WARNING:root:You are using the default
>   Django version (0.96). The default
>   Django version will change in an App
>   Engine release in the near future.
>   Please call use_library() to
>   explicitly select a Django version.
>   For more information see
>   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

The link the error provides seems to only talk about using:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

If I was using GAE's django I understand I'd need to do this. However, I'm using django-nonrel, why would it warn me I'm using 0.96 when I should be using 1.3?

Comment: Are you for some reason using the webapp framework as well as django? The warning is found in `google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py`.

Comment: I guess that's showing my ignorance on the matter because I'm not sure. How do I check that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check your project's PYTHONPATH setting (right-click the project, click on Preferences, and select PYTHONPATH)? Make sure that you do NOT have the GAE SDK's django folder in your PYTHONPATH. If it's listed there just remove it. This should get rid of the warning.

Comment: I didn't have the django folder added as an external library, but I did have the entire folder "/usr/local/google_appengine" as one of the external libraries. I removed it and I haven't seen the warning and everything is still working, so I think we're good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with Django-nonrel yet. If not for that, and your using Django 1.3, then adding

```
webapp_django_version = '1.2'
```

to `appengine_config.py` (and removing uses of `use_library`) would solve your problem. Since you're already set up to run the experiment, try

```
webapp_django_version = '1.3'
```

and report back.